# Scaffold + Send Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have scaffold named `users` with fields: `email, surname.`

I inserted about `10 users.`

Bottom of the scaffold there are button called `"Send"`.

When i pressed this button email receive all 10 people with following text => `"Hello! my number is 718927 (this is generated by rand(9999) for example)."`

How can i do it? Can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ActionMailer here.

Basic knowledge: http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

Little more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html